# Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo un documento PHP para hacer un update en una tabla pero al momento de hacer el update me manda este mensaje:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/aabdesig/public_html/actualizar_direccion.php:3) in /home/aabdesig/public_html/actualizar_direccion.php on line 57
```

Y no redirige a la pagina. Este es el codigo:

```
<?php 
$pagina_actual = $_POST['page'];
echo $pagina_actual;
$folio= $_POST['id'];
$nombre= $_POST['nombre'];
$mp= $_POST['mp'];
$hora= $_POST['hora'];

/* Recibe fecha de entrega del form */
$fecha_ent= $_POST['fecha_ent'];
/* ------------------------ */

/* Consigue la semana de acuerdo a la fecha de entrega */
$ddate = $fecha_ent;
$date = new DateTime($ddate);
$week = $date->format("W");
// Variable con el numero de la semana
$sem_ent= $week;
/* --------------------------------------------------- */

/* Recibe fecha del sistema */
$fecha_reg= date("Y/m/d");
/* ----------------------------- */

$dir= $_POST['dir'];
$resistencia= $_POST['resistencia'];
$pu= $_POST['pu'];
$tiro= $_POST['tiro'];
$m3= $_POST['m3'];
$ton= $_POST['ton'];
$rev= $_POST['revenimiento'];
$add= $_POST['add'];
$hostname = "Localhost";
$username = "aabdesig_admin";
$password = "aabdesign2018";
$database = "aabdesig_registros";
$conexion = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $database) or die ("Problemas con la conexion"); ("Problemas con la conexion");
mysqli_select_db($conexion,$database) or die ("problemas con la base de datos");
$string="update registros
     set cliente='".$nombre."',
     metodo_pago='Credito ".$mp."D',
     hora='".$hora."',
     fecha_entrega='".$fecha_ent."',
     sem_entrega='".$sem_ent."',
     dir_obra='".$dir."',
     resistencia='".$resistencia."',
     pu='".$pu."',
     tiro='".$tiro."',
     m3='".$m3."',
     ton='".$ton."',
     revenimiento='".$rev."',
     adicionales='".$add."'
     where id='".$folio."'";
mysqli_query($conexion,$string) or die ("Problemas con el update"); 
mysqli_close($conexion);
echo"Update exitoso";
header('Location: ' . $pagina_actual);
exit;?>
```

De antemano muchas gracias por sus respuestas.

Comment: Es por que estas imprimiendo echo "Update exitoso"; Quita eso y prueba.

Comment: Wow, muy facil y efectivo, muchas gracias amiga.